# Java execution -o option

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

What is the meaning of option "-o" while execution jar or java class through command line

```
java -jar a.jar argument1 argument2 -o some_file_path
```

Thank you

Comment: This information could definitely be found in the documentation. If not, it's probably a command line option handled by the main entry point of the application a.jar

Comment: @Antwane I have searched in documentation, but did not get the solution. it mean this is customized option not java defined ?

Comment: Yes, the answers below should help you. This is related to your application. Without more information (a.jar is not really helpful), nobody will be able to tell exactly what is the meaning of this -o option. But as NPE said, this is usually an 'output' option or something approaching

Answer (score 4):

It's a command-line argument passed to `a.jar`.

Its meaning depends on `a.jar`; however, by convention `-o filename` often specifies the output file.

Comment: how to use it in java class ? same as normal argument ?

Comment: @AnkitSharma: It will show up in the string array passed to `main()`.

Comment: When I am running jar with this option. It is taking "-o" as an argument  and file_path is next argument. So What is the significance of it.Thank you...

Answer (score 2):

Everething after `java -jar a.jar` is passed as argument to main method

Comment: yes. this thing I know, but what is significance of -o here.

Comment: Its depend on what you run. It is infinite amount of possibilities. You better ask author of `a.jar`

Comment: okay. I think it is customized option. Thank you for your time.